# undefined method `email=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get [facebook cleaner](https://github.com/netcrawler/Facebook-Cleaner) to work, however it fails with the following message:

```
./lib/facebook.rb:140:in `get_home': undefined method `email=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):23:in `form_with'
    from ./lib/facebook.rb:139:in `get_home'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb:409:in `get'
    from ./lib/facebook.rb:137:in `get_home'
    from ./lib/facebook.rb:38:in `setup'
    from fb_cleaner.rb:34
```

and this is the code from line 136 to 145;

```
def get_home
  @a.get(MOBILE_URL) do |page|
    sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    @home = page.form_with(:action => "https://login.facebook.com/login.php?m=m") do |f|
      f.email = @email
      f.pass = @password
    end.submit
  end
  @home
end # get_home
```

anyone got a clue?

Comment: Your question is so hard to read that you'll be lucky if someone can help you. You should edit it :)

Comment: @Agis: You could have fixed the formatting yourself with just a couple keystrokes...

Comment: @muistooshort I'd rather explain to people why wearing a sunblock under the summer sun is a good idea, rather than applying it to them myself. win/win

Answer (score 1):

The last commit in this library is 2 years ago. Chances are the Facebook interface changed in the meanwhile.

Other users are experiencing the same issue, there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/netcrawler/Facebook-Cleaner/issues/1) dated 2 years ago.

I think it's reasonable to say that the library is no longer working and also it appears to be unmaintained.